# setGeometry fails setting top coordinate using Qt6 on OS X

Tags: qt, screen, qt6

I am creating a method called `showLeftAligned` to force the geometry of a QDialog to be left aligned on screen, separated by a gap of `gap` pixels around.

```cpp
void QXDialog::showLeftAligned(int gap) {
  QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->availableGeometry();
  setGeometry(s.x() + gap, s.y() + gap, width(), s.height() - 2 * gap);
  QDialog::show();
}
```

As you can see, I am using the screen `availableGeometry` to take into account the upper menu bar or/and the lower docker. In my case, docker is hidden but OSX menu is set to be always on.

The problem with this method is that the top y-coordinate of the resulting dialog does not separates `gap` pixels below the menu bar. Here is the **result for a gap of 32 pixels**.

[image: showLeftAligned result]

Using `QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->geometry()` Qt is getting right the logical size of the screen, which is `1440 x 900 @ 60.00Hz`. Moving to `QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->geometry()` I get `1440 x 875`, 25 pixels less due to the upper menu bar.

So, everything seems to be logical here but the top position of the QDialog keeps being wrong.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust the position with the window frame. See the picture and explanation of the difference between geometry and frame geometry here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/application-windows.html#window-geometry Your final code can look like this.

```
void QXDialog::showLeftAligned(int gap) {
    show(); // we must call this before measuring the window geometry
    auto s = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->availableGeometry();
    s.adjust(gap, gap, -gap, -gap);
    auto rect = geometry();
    auto frameRect = frameGeometry();
    auto topLeftDiff = rect.topLeft() - frameRect.topLeft();
    auto bottomRightDiff = rect.bottomRight() - frameRect.bottomRight();
    s.adjust(topLeftDiff.x(), topLeftDiff.y(), bottomRightDiff.x(), bottomRightDiff.y());
    setGeometry(s);
}
```